# What is the simplest algorithm to compress a string?

Tags: algorithms, strings, data-compression

I need to compress a string in my application but I am very limited in the operations I can perform. In particular, I cannot store data in any file and I cannot query any database. Also, I cannot call any library so I have to code my own data compression algorithm. What would be the simplest algorithm to achieve this goal?
I could code the smaz algorithm myself but it does not seem to work very well with long strings.

Comment: You need lossless compression I assume?

Comment: I do need lossless compression.

Comment: My favourite algorithm for this is Deflate. You have a good starting document on this one here: http://pnrsolution.org/Datacenter/Vol4/Issue1/58.pdf

Comment: It is definitely not the simplest one though. It is the best.

Comment: Beyond puns like *one with the best possible worst case compression is **copy***, I'm fond of [PackBits](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/PackBits) for its handling of non-repetitive stuff.

Comment: `I am very limited in the operations I can perform […] I have to code my own data compression algorithm` in a [Turing complete](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) notation? No special limit there.

Comment: Implementations for [simple compression algorithms at Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Compression).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need something reasonably effective but not very taxing to implement, I would recommend [LZW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch).

LZW has several advantages, not the least of which is that it uses fixed-width codes (the width strictly increases as compression proceeds), rather than Huffman or arithmetic coding. It also does not require string searching through a sliding window, instead performing hash table or tree lookup per input character. This means that it requires significantly less code to implement than methods based on LZ77.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest (besides "no compression at all") is [RLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding).

RLE is useless on many kinds of data, but better kinds of general-purpose compression require more complex algorithms.

Comment: It is simple indeed and it does not require any external data. However, I am looking for something a little more efficient than this. I want to encode a json string or an xml string. I am not sure RLE will be very useful for that case.

Comment: If it's json consider using the msgpack format? Maybe together with RLE for msgpack strings. If you only need a subset of json it might be easy to implement a parser yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the idea but msgpack does not look like a simple algorithm to code yourself and unfortunately I cannot rely on any external library.

Comment: The title of your question specifies "simplest" and RLE is certainly one of the simplest compression methods around. If you want something that is also efficient you should rephrase your question.

Answer (score 2):

My vote goes to LZP. It's hilariously simple.

It should be drastically simpler and faster than anything that uses trees in any capacity, such as Huffman coding, LZW or practically every compression algorithm that remotely tries to achieve better compression. Compression ratios aren't great however, works better on longer strings.

Here's a complete working implementation in C i adapted from [here](https://github.com/lmcilroy/lzp):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define HASH_SIZE   (1 << 16)
#define HASH(h, x)  (h = (h << 4) ^ x)

void encode(unsigned char *input, unsigned int inputlen, unsigned char *output, unsigned int *outlen) {
    unsigned char buf[9], table[HASH_SIZE] = {0};
    unsigned short hash = 0;
    int mask, i, j, c, inpos = 0, outpos = 0;
    
    for (;;) {
        j = 1;
        mask = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            if (inpos == inputlen) break;
            c = input[inpos++];
            if (c == table[hash]) {
                mask |= 1 << i;
            } else {
                table[hash] = c;
                buf[j++] = c;
            }
            HASH(hash, c);
        }
        if (i > 0) {
            buf[0] = mask;
            for (i=0;i<j;i++) { output[outpos++] = buf[i]; } // one-liner copy function
        }
        if (inpos == inputlen) break;
    }
    *outlen = outpos;
}

void decode(unsigned char *input, unsigned int inputlen, unsigned char *output, unsigned int *outlen) {
    unsigned char buf[8], table[HASH_SIZE] = {0};
    unsigned short hash = 0;
    int mask, i, j, c, inpos = 0, outpos = 0;
    
    for (;;) {
        j = 0;
        if (inpos == inputlen) break;
        mask = input[inpos++];
        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            if ((mask & (1 << i)) != 0) {
                c = table[hash];
            } else {
                if (inpos == inputlen) break;
                c = input[inpos++];
                table[hash] = c;
            }
            buf[j++] = c;
            HASH(hash, c);
        }
        if (j > 0) {
            for (i=0;i<j;i++) { output[outpos++] = buf[i]; } // one-liner copy function
        }
    }
    *outlen = outpos;
}

int main(){
    unsigned int strlen = 82, outlen;
    unsigned char str[1024] = "Fuzzy Wuzzy was a bear. Fuzzy Wuzzy had no hair. Fuzzy Wuzzy wasn't fuzzy, was he?";
    unsigned char out[1024];
    
    printf("original length: %d\n", strlen);
    for (int i=0;i<strlen;i++) { printf("%c", str[i]); }
    printf("\n\n");
    
    encode(str, strlen, out, &outlen);
    
    printf("encoded length: %d\n", outlen);
    for (int i=0;i<outlen;i++) { printf("%d ", out[i]); }
    printf("\n\n");
    
    decode(out, outlen, str, &strlen);
    
    printf("decoded length: %d\n", strlen);
    for (int i=0;i<strlen;i++) { printf("%c", str[i]); }
    printf("\n\n");
}
```